# statechanging method

Tags: c#, user-interface, methods, unity-game-engine, boolean

It's just a simple noobie question...
I often use something like this(code) to change my GUI, so my question is if there's something more useful than using bool variables?

Thanks!

//Unity3D - C#

```
public class GuiBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
  private bool lookInside = false;

  void OnGUI ()
  {
    if (!lookInside) {
        if (GUILayout.Button ("Look Inside")) {
            lookInside = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (GUILayout.Button ("Exit View")) {
            lookInside = false;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
lookInside =!lookInside;

if(lookInside)
{
  GUILayout.Button ("Look Inside")
}
else
{
   GUILayout.Button ("Exit View")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different handlers for different buttons, assumes buttons are only visible in either view.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
        lookInsideButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        lookInsideButton.Click += new EventHandler(lookInsideButton_Click);

        exitViewButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        exitViewButton.Click += new EventHandler(exitViewButton_Click);
}

void lookInsideButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowInsideView();
}

void exitViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExitInsideView();
}

System.Windows.Forms.Button lookInsideButton, exitViewButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use enum for better readability and to have more than 2 states. For example:

```
public class GuiBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
  private GUIState CurrentState;
  enum GUIState
  {
    LookInside,
    ExitView,
    GameOverView
  }

  void OnGUI(GUIState state)
  {
    CurrentState = state;
    switch(state)
    {
       case GUIState.LookInside:
         GUILayout.Button("Look Inside");
         break;
       case GUIState.ExitView:
         GUILayout.Button("Exit View");
         break;
       case GUIState.LookInside:
         GUILayout.Button("Game over");
         break;
     }
  }
}
```